# Read XML file from a file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7.1

I have a xml file with this structure. The node "settings" is repeated only 1 time. The node "Reminders" can appear + 1 time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Name App-->
<AllSettings>
  <Settings>
    <tax1>21</tax1>
    <tax2>0</tax2>    
  </Settings>
  <Reminders>
    <Name>s8</Name>
    <Title>xxxxx</Title>
    <Content>xxxxxxxxx</Content>
    <BeginTime>09/11/2012 10:00:00</BeginTime>
  </Reminders>
  <Reminders>
    <Name>s2</Name>
    <Title>zzzzzzzzz</Title>
    <Content>zzzzzzzzzzz</Content>
    <BeginTime>07/11/2012 13:00:00</BeginTime>    
  </Reminders>  
</AllSettings>
```

I can read data in "settings" node using the bottom code. But how I can read the data from each node "reminders"?

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(myXmlFile, FileMode.Open);
isoFileStream.Position = 0;
XmlReader xmlReader;
xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(isoFileStream);                                           
xmlReader.MoveToContent(); 

while (xmlReader.Read())
{    

  if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.LocalName == "Settings"
  {
     while (xmlReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
     {
          xmlReader.Read();

          if (xmlReader.Name == "tax1")
          {
                _tax1 = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
          }
          else if (xmlReader.Name == "tax2")
          {
                _tax2 = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
          }

      } // end while
  } 
  else if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xmlReader.LocalName == "Reminders")
  {
       // ????            
  }

} // end while
```

Comment: Do an inner loop to read until you hit the end of the Reminder element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load it into an `XDocument` and query using LINQ to XML.

```
var isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(myXmlFile, FileMode.Open);
isoFileStream.Position = 0;

var xdoc = XDocument.Load(isoFileStream);
var reminderNodes = from n in xdoc.Descendants("Reminders") select n;

foreach (var n in reminderNodes)
{
    ProcessReminder(n);
}

void ProcessReminder(XElement node)
{
    // do something... for now I'll just output to console.
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", n.Element("Name").Value); 
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", n.Element("Title").Value);
    Console.WriteLine("BeginTime: {0}", n.Element("BeginTime").Value);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq2Xml is much more easier

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
var reminders = xDoc.Descendants("Reminders")
                    .Select(r => new
                    {
                        Name = (string)r.Element("Name"),
                        Title = (string)r.Element("Title"),
                        Content = (string)r.Element("Content"),
                        BeginTime = (DateTime)r.Element("BeginTime"),
                    })
                    .ToList();

var firstTitle = reminders[0].Title;
```

or

```
var remDicts = xDoc.Descendants("Reminders")
       .Select(r => r.Elements().ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => e.Value))
       .ToList();

var firstTitle = remDicts[0]["Title"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using XmlNode.Value instead of getting data from the XmlReader.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use xsd.exe tool to generate .XSD from XM and C# class from .XSD, and after that, just use LINQ syntax to interrogate.

[This might help](http://sharpertutorials.com/using-xsd-tool-to-generate-classes-from-xml/) or [this search](https://www.google.ro/#hl=ro&gs_nf=3&tok=wnG-sYLw0RJvqnK-VHCzqg&cp=30&gs_id=3h&xhr=t&q=how+to+generate+class+from+xml+in+c#&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=how+to+generate+class+from+xml&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=49e81df317ab57ce&bpcl=37189454&biw=1680&bih=935)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a XmlDocument instead of an XmlReader